# Insert several datasets for several IDs

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of users:

```
UserID    | User
1           Martin
2           Lilian
3           Oliver
```

Now I have another table:

```
dataID | UserID | key | value
```

Now what I need to do is:

Select certain users from the user-table and insert several recrods in the data-table:

I need to combine these two querys:

```
INSERT INTO `data` (`UserID`, `key`, `value`)
VALUES (HERE_ID_OF_USER, 'someKey', 10),
VALUES (HERE_ID_OF_USER, 'otherKey', 20)

SELECT `UserID` FROM `users` WHERE ...
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand what you want to do, but I'll assume you want this:

```
INSERT INTO data (UserID,key,value) SELECT UserID,'somekey',10 FROM users WHERE ...
INSERT INTO data (UserID,key,value) SELECT UserID,'otherkey',20 FROM users WHERE ...
```

If that's not what you want, you'll need to be a bit more explicit...

**Update**

If you already have the data you want to insert for each user in a table, you can use:

```
INSERT INTO data (UserID,key,value)
    SELECT u.UserID,dd.key,dd.value FROM users u,default_data dd WHERE ...
```

If you don't (and don't want to store it in a table), you can use;

```
INSERT INTO data (UserID,key,value)
    SELECT UserID,'some key',10 FROM users WHERE ...
    UNION ALL
    SELECT UserID,'other key',20 FROM users WHERE ...
```

or (to avoid the repetition of the `WHERE` clause):

```
INSERT INTO data (UserId,key,value)
    SELECT u.UserID,dd.key,dd.value
        FROM users u,
            (
                SELECT 'some key' AS key,10 AS data
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 'other key',20
            ) dd
        WHERE ...
```

There are probably more ways to do it.

Comment: Isn't there a way to combine everything in on query? That's the whole point of the question. :)

Comment: The point of the questions was not quite explicit. As it stands, it meant you wanted to combine the `INSERT` and `SELECT` into a single query, which is what the above does. I'll add additional options to combine both `INSERT`s into a single query.

Comment: What would be better? Creating one huge query with all the inserts or select the userIDs once, loop through them with PHP and then insert the data one by one?

Comment: The less queries you have, the faster it will be, as each query adds query preparation (parsing, planning...), logging, and possibly latency if the php interpreter and the SQL server are not on the same box.

Answer (score 0):

Build your select query to fetch data from 2 table based on User ID join. Then insert the result set into the desired table.

INSERT INTO DATA (SELECT A.USER_ID, B.KEY, B.VALUE FROM USERS A, SECOND_TABLE B WHERE A.USER_ID = B.USER_ID AND A.USER_ID IN (.....))

Comment: The key and value is static data. That's not coming from a table.

Comment: Then build up the insert statement and pass those static values from server side code like Java or, PHP in prepared statement through a for loop.